# Modify requestHeaders in "custom" browser in delphi

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I have a browser integrated in my deplhi application (IE). I need to call a certain web app and I need to append a new variable in the header for all the requests that come from my application's browser, like jquery adds to the xhrobj the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` parameter. Any idea on how can I do that? code samples would be great. I am usin `TWebBrowser`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can modify the headers with the `OnBeforeNavigate2` event:

```
procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1BeforeNavigate2(Sender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData,
  Headers: OleVariant; var Cancel: WordBool);
var
  NewHeaders: OleVariant;
begin
  // do not allow frames or iframes to raise this event
  if (pDisp as IUnknown) = (WebBrowser1.ControlInterface as IUnknown) then
  begin
    // avoid stack overflow: check if our custom header is already set
    if Pos('MyHeader', Headers) <> 0 then Exit;

    // cancel the current navigation
    Cancel := True;
    (pDisp as IWebBrowser2).Stop;

    // modify headers with our custom header
    NewHeaders := Headers + 'MyHeader: Value'#13#10;

    (pDisp as IWebBrowser2).Navigate2(URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData, NewHeaders);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

[IWebBrowser2.Navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb415532.aspx) has a parameter that lets you define additional headers.