# Delphi TWebBrowser PostData incomplete for OnBeforeNavigate2 event

Tags: delphi, http-post, twebbrowser

I want to modify the headers of a request with TWebBrowser in Delphi XE5.  As described in [Modify requestHeaders in “custom” browser in delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210507/modify-requestheaders-in-custom-browser-in-delphi), you can do that using the OnBeforeNavigate2 event of the TWebBrowser. The procedure corresponding to the event would be:

```
procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1BeforeNavigate2(Sender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData,
  Headers: OleVariant; var Cancel: WordBool);

var
  NewHeaders: OleVariant;
begin
  // some code to stop the navigation, enhance the headers and avoid re-enterng the procedure

  // do not allow frames or iframes to raise this event
  if (pDisp as IUnknown) = (WebBrowser1.ControlInterface as IUnknown)     then
  begin
    // avoid stack overflow: check if our custom header is already set
    if Pos('MyHeader', Headers) <> 0 then Exit;

    // cancel the current navigation
    Cancel := True;
    (pDisp as IWebBrowser2).Stop;

    // modify headers with our custom header
    NewHeaders := Headers + 'MyHeader: Value'#13#10;
    // now proceed with navigation 
    (pDisp as IWebBrowser2).Navigate(URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData, NewHeaders);
  end;
end;
```

The problem is that while the method proposed in the answer works for a GET request, for a POST request I run into the following problem: PostData only contains the beginning of the initially posted data (in my case a text file uploaded via a html form). Concretely, while a correct example of what a client sends back to the server would look like this:

```
--AaB03x
    content-disposition: form-data; name="field1"

    Joe Blow
    --AaB03x
    content-disposition: form-data; name="pics"; filename="file1.txt"
    Content-Type: text/plain

     ... contents of file1.txt ...
--AaB03x--
```

what I find while debugging as PostData is something like this
PostString

```
'-----------------------------7e16'#$D#$A'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="myform"; filename="MyUploadedFile.csv"'#$D#$A'Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'#$D#$A#$D#$A#0
```

Hence the entire content of the file is missing and the final boundary (i.e. -----------------------------7e16).

WireShark tells me that despite PostData is not NULL `Navigate()` is not making a POST request but a GET with a message body being exactly what I found during debugging and show above.

My guess is that the reason for the latter is that the `Navigate()` function performs a check on whether PostData is valid before it creates a POST request and it makes a GET otherwise.

Since someone claims that `Navigate()` works correctly with PostData what can I do to get the complete PostData for my `OnBeforeNavigate2` event?

Comment: Hard to tell what is going on. Can you make a complete example that exposes the problem?

Comment: @whosrdaddy I just posted code that adds a header "MyHeader" with the value "Value" to the headers before the navigation. As I said this works fine unless your request is a POST, e.g. the user filled out a html form in the Web Browser.

Comment: In the source code I see two `begin` but only one `end`. Where is the second end?

Comment: If `PostData` is incomplete than you are likely reading its data incorrectly. A browser would not post incomplete data, and certainly would not change a request from `POST` to `GET` based on the content of post data.  The only thing that should ever change a request type from `POST` to `GET` is an HTTP redirect.  If `PostData` is passed to `Navigate()` than it issues a `POST` request, not a `GET` request, period. This is documented behavior.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The way I read PostData while debugging is: `PostString := TEncoding.ANSI.GetString(TBytes(PostData));`, but I am not responsible for the variable in the first place, since it is already set when the event is triggered. In addition, what I find while debugging is consistent with what WireShark is intercepting. I changed the question  to reflect that in fact all I will probably need to achieve is to somehow get the complete PostData.